# Different datatypes of chromosome for GA in R

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I wish to implement a Genetic algorithm in R, in which the chromosome consists of two variables.
The problem I have is that I want one variable to take integer values while the other to float values.

R has two packages for genetic algorithms:

1.) [GA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/GA.pdf)-This allows us to take only float values of the variables in chromosome.
Following is the implementation code"

```
 GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = function(x) f(x[1],x[2]),
          min = c(0,0), max =c(1,2),popsize = 2)

  #f is some single objective function which takes 2 input parameters
```

2.)[gramEvol](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/electrical/cel/UserFiles/File/Anthony/GramEvol/gramEvol-manual.pdf)- This packages allows us to integer values of variables in chromosome solely.

But I couldn't find any package which allows the variables in the chromosome to be of different data types for example one integer and one float as I wish to achieve.

I don't wish to code the whole genetic algorithm from scratch in R as the it would be redundant and given these packages work quite well. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**(Response to first comment)**:**
The objective function when taking floating values (from GA) for the integer variable simply rounds them off. What you are saying is exactly what I do right now.
But this would make the search space quite large which could be reduced considerably .

For example: 2.4 and 2.5 would result in same value for the function, but GA implementation would consider them as two different values and search space would be thus similarly quite larger when we consider all such values.

Comment: Why not take GA where float variables can also take integer values? Use round(var,0) if needed.